# ItemizedOverlay hitTest

Tags: android

I'm using this method to detect whether someone clicks on an overlay. Now everything works except for that the click area is too small. So I looked at the api which said "See if a given hit point is within the bounds of an item's marker. ".

I made my bounds bigger like this:

```
Log.d("debug", "Marker propertie 1: "  + marker.getBounds());   //output:Marker propertie 1: Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)

Rect square = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);
marker.setBounds(square);
Log.d("debug", "Marker propertie 2: "  + marker.getBounds());   //output:Marker propertie 2: Rect(0, 0 - 200, 200)
if (hitTest(item, marker, x-p.x, y-p.y)) {
//...
}
```

But both ways of changing its bounds doesn't change the click-area. Can someone hint me how I can increase the clickarea of my drawables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the google maps api? If you want to extend the bound you can overide the hitTest of your extended itemizedOverlay to something like this.

```
@Override
protected boolean hitTest(OverlayItem overlayItem, Drawable drawable, int x, int y) {
    Rect bounds = drawable.getBounds();
    int newLeft = (int) (200 * ((double)bounds.left / (double)bounds.width())  ) ;
    int newTop = (int) (200 * ((double)bounds.top  / (double)bounds.height()) );
    Rect square = new Rect(newLeft, newTop, 200, 200);
    return square.contains(x, y);
}
```

Just tested on a map I have seems to work.

Comment: Also remember to adjust the hardcoded 200 to something that works better in you app. I seem to get the new bound to far down so you should check the newTop to see if it is calculated correctly on your map.