# Why are my marker-info windows showing on another marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am currently trying to build an app with multiple different markers in a single city, but when I click one of the markers, the info window appears for another marker, even though the coordinates are different.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Java code,

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.rsz_marker))
    .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
    .anchor((float).5,(float).5)
    .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("population")))
    .infoWindowAnchor((float).5,(float).46)
    .position(latLng));
```

And here is a screenshot of what is happening (I clicked on the left marker): 
[image: MapView]

Comment: Please try again by zooming as much as you can and having both of the markers in your screen area. Does it work? If yes then it's propably a sensitivity issue from the Google Map API

Comment: @Try_me34 it works when I zoom in, but I need the app to at least be zoomed to this level because I want to cover a fairly large area.  Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default marker clickable area. There was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5876) but afrer the release of GoogleMap API v2 it was fixed. There used to be a workaround around that issue [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866588/itemizedoverlay-hittest), (Overriding `hitTest`), but this technique applied to the previous version of GoogleMap.

IMHO, setting larger marker size should fix your issue. Somewhere near 36x36 (hdpi) should be okay.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up scaling the markers to a 58x46 ratio, and it worked fine.